# pip install nlp no matching distribution found

Tags: python, spacy

I am new to Ubuntu and Python and practicing the Spacy library for Python. I am following [this tutorial](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/lightning-tour) for the Spacy library, which is using the `nlp` module. Thus, I have to install it, but when I use following command

```
pip install nlp
```

Then it gives following results:

```
Collecting nlp
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement nlp (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for nlp
```

I searched it but did not find any solution till now.

Comment: nlp = spacy.load('en') ?

Comment: Try updating your pip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the spacy modul that you need to install.

```
pip install spacy
```

Then you can use its nlp:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp(u"Apples and oranges are similar. Boots and hippos aren't.")
```